# Generate multiples text files in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, text

I used the following code to generate my text file:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text; 

public class SomeController {

// this action will create text file 'your_file_name.txt' with data from
// string variable 'string_with_your_data', which will be downloaded by
// your browser
public FileStreamResult CreateFile() {
    //todo: add some data from your database into that string:
    var string_with_your_data = "";

    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string_with_your_data);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);


        return File(stream, "text/plain", "your_file_name.txt");   
    }
}
```

I used to use this way:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "plain/text";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "File1" + ".txt");
Response.Output.WriteLine("Content File 1");
Response.End();
```

But now I want to generate multiple files, each one with it own content.

**Example:**

```
File1.txt - Content 1, File2.txt - Content 2, File3.txt - Content 3
```

Can I do that or will I have to zip all the files?

And than I want to reload my page, because I have a grid that show the files generated. But when I used Response.End() I'm killing all process after it.

If I was not clear I can explain more.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you need to send back all generated files to client?

Comment: Yes, the client need all the separated files

Comment: Then you have to zip them, see duplicate. One HTTP request equals one response, and one response can only contain one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891024/how-to-download-multiple-files-getting-server-cannot-clear-headers-after-http/27892632#27892632) post. Same approach you may like to choose for your solution.
If zipping is not option then you need to use ajax to download individual file. But in that case you should know number of files and names upfront to make those many ajax calls.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this, I think this is the correct alternative.